# propblem to call action function is redux i have a message : this.props.nameofprops.action() is not a fction

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typeerror

I'm writing a react-redux code I defined an action to called in the componant, it's called addCart.

```
import axios from "axios"
import {GET_PLATS} from "./actionType"
 
 

export const getplats = () => dispatch => {
    // 2-1 axions get the same path of back in app.use
    axios.get("/plat-list").then(res => {
        dispatch({
            //2-2 same name in action type (after this go to make reducers)
            type:GET_PLATS,
            payload:res.data
        })
    }) 
}

export const addCart =( ) =>{
    return (dispatch) => {
         
        console.log("added To cart");
        dispatch({
            type:GET_PLATS,
            
        })
    }
}
```

then I've wrote this reducer:

```
import { GET_PLATS } from "../action/actionType"

//first create first main state
const initialState={
    plats:[],
    cmdElements:[]
}

export default function(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PLATS:
             return{
                 ...state,
                 plats:action.payload,
                 cmdElements:state.cmdElements
              
             }
             default : 
              return  state

        }
    
}
```

Then I called this action in a component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {getplats,addCart } from '../../action/action'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
const { Meta } = Card
 

 class PlatListeU extends Component {
 
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getplats()        
    }
  render() {
        return (
    <div>
     <Button type="primary" onClick={ () =>{ 
                      this.props.platListe.addCart()
                  } } >addTocart</Button>

    </div>
)}

PlatListeU.propTypes = {
    addCart:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    PlatListe:PropTypes.object.isRequired

}


const mapStateToProps =(state) =>{
    return{
        platListe:state.plats ,
         cmdElements:state.cmdElements
    
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ getplats,addCart}) (PlatListeU)
```

But when I press on the button, I have this error message:

> TypeError: this.props.platListe.addCart is not a function

Everything should be fine. I tried a lot of ways but the result is the same . Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you define ``platListe`` as one of your props?

Comment: as you see in the code yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `this.props.addCart()`. You import the methods in the component, not in `platListe`. Thus the error.

For the other error:

it looks like your reducers are mapped correctly. so state.moviesReducer is always defined.

if your initial list of items doesn't even load correctly, means your items object are causing the error.

if your initial list loads correctly, and the error occurs only after you dispatch the action, means your update() is mutating your state shape.

I don't know where you are getting this update function. but i am guessing you should just return{items:update(..)}

This is how I would go about debugging your code.

Comment: Solve it? Just change this.props.platListe.addCart() to this.props.addCart(). Easy.

Comment: this is work but i have this new error message 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react redux

Comment: Then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621788/how-do-i-deal-with-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-react-redux).

Comment: as your see the initial map work correctly so it's not a problem of initial state

Comment: sorry but i did not  understood the rest

Comment: Whatever. I found out that you *copied* all of your code to another question. I have shown the code to you, so you can try to understand the rest. "sorry but i did not understood the rest" does not mean that you have to post another question over again.

Comment: Also you should be able to understand the rest if you are good at understanding React works. By the way, can you please send me how you update the initial list and dispatch the action?

Comment: i don't have this error  but this is my problem now
the action is became functional but i have a new problem when i press on the click button the initial map became dysfunctionaland i don't have any view of the first map to make it clear this is the image of my view before the click and after the click : ibb.co/Tb4q2f4 and when i click this is the result ibb.co/4mD3PMK as you see in the console the action is functional but the result is bad by the way this is my action : export const addCart =( ) =>{ console.log("added to cart") return { type:GET_PLATS } } –

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just `this.props.addCart()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want `this.props.addCart()`. The key `platListe` exists in your state object, it does not have any methods attached to it. You import the standalone methods at the top of your component.

Comment: how can i attached the method to the props