# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I made this select to filter the result in the front end and it seems to be working, but when I click on my `addTocart` button I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Here is my component's code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getplats, addCart } from "../../action/action";
import { Card, Button } from "antd";
import Cart from "../Cart/Cart";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./PlatListeU.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const { Meta } = Card;

class PlatListeU extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: "",
            searchOrigine: "",
            searchGout: "",
            cmd: "",
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getplats();
    }

    updateSearched(event) {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0, 20) });
    }

    updateSearchedOrigine(event) {
        this.setState({ searchOrigine: event.target.value });
    }

    updateSearchedGout(event) {
        this.setState({ searchGout: event.target.value });
    }
    //midfy
    addCmd(event) {
        this.setState({
            cmd: event.target.value,
        });
    }
    handleClick(ele) {
        this.props.cmdElements.push(ele);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        {" "}
                        Restaurant{" "}
                    </a>
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
                    </button>
                    <div
                        class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                        id="navbarNavAltMarkup"
                    >
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">
                                {" "}
                                cart{" "}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="press name"
                        value={this.state.search}
                        onChange={this.updateSearched.bind(this)}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <br />
                    <select
                        name="origine"
                        value={this.state.searchOrigine}
                        onChange={this.updateSearchedOrigine.bind(this)}
                    >
                        {uniq(this.props.platListe.map((el) => el.origine)).map(
                            (el) => (
                                <option>{el} </option>
                            )
                        )}
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <select
                        name="gout"
                        value={this.state.searchGout}
                        onChange={this.updateSearchedGout.bind(this)}
                    >
                        {uniq(this.props.platListe.map((el) => el.nature)).map(
                            (el) => (
                                <option>{el} </option>
                            )
                        )}
                    </select>
                </form>

                <br />
                <div className="list">
                    {this.props.platListe
                        .filter((plat) => {
                            return (
                                plat.name
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
                            );
                        })
                        .filter((plat) => {
                            return (
                                plat.origine.indexOf(
                                    this.state.searchOrigine
                                ) !== -1
                            );
                        })
                        .filter((plat) => {
                            return (
                                plat.nature.indexOf(this.state.searchGout) !==
                                -1
                            );
                        })
                        .map((el, li) => (
                            <div>
                                <Card
                                    hoverable
                                    style={{ width: 240 }}
                                    cover={
                                        <img
                                            alt="example"
                                            src={el.image}
                                            style={{ width: 240, height: 180 }}
                                        />
                                    }
                                >
                                    name : <Meta title={el.name} />
                                    price: <Meta title={el.price} />
                                    origine: <Meta title={el.origine} />
                                    gout: <Meta title={el.nature} />
                                    <Button
                                        type="primary"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            this.props.addCart();
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {" "}
                                        addTocart{" "}
                                    </Button>
                                </Card>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

PlatListeU.propTypes = {
    addCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    PlatListe: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        platListe: state.plats,
        cmdElements: state.cmdElements,
    };
};

export function uniq(arr) {
    return arr.filter((value, index) => arr.indexOf(value) === index);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getplats, addCart })(PlatListeU);
```

this is my reducers

```
import { GET_PLATS } from "../action/actionType"
 
const initialState={
    plats:[],
    cmdElements:[]
}

export default function(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PLATS:
             return{
                 ...state,
                 plats:action.payload,
                 cmdElements:state.cmdElements
              
             }
             default : 
              return  state

        }
```

Comment: there are some variables that you want to map through but the variable is set to null, your code is broad and you can debug it easily by yourself. check all the variables values before mapping through them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" react/redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621788/how-do-i-deal-with-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-react-redux)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.platListe.map(...)
```

It looks the error is from the above code. Your `platListe` is `undefined` so cannot use `map` function on it.

```js
const mapStateToProps =(state) =>{
    return{
        platListe:state.plats ,
         cmdElements:state.cmdElements
        
    }
}
```

You are mapping the `state.plats` as `platListe` in your props so I think `plats` property at your redux store is `undefined` or `null`(not array).

You just need to make sure the `state.plats` is available as an array.
Or an simple workaround:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        platListe:state.plats || [],
        cmdElements:state.cmdElements
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.props.cmdElements.push(ele)` you call this?

Comment: thank you know the action is became functional but i have a new problem when i press on the click button the initial map became dysfunctionaland i don't have any view of the first map to make it clear this is the image of my view before the click and after the click : ibb.co/Tb4q2f4 and when i click this is the result https://ibb.co/4mD3PMK as you see in the console the action is functional but the result is bad by the way this is my action : export const addCart =( ) =>{     console.log("added to cart")     return  {  type:GET_PLATS   } }

Comment: can you add your reducer as well?

Comment: this is my initial state in the store :
const initialState={
    plats:[],
    cmdElements:[]
}

Comment: and what do you do in your reduce when the button is clicked?

Comment: i wrote you my reducers

Answer (score 0):

this is my reducers

```
import { GET_PLATS } from "../action/actionType"
 
const initialState={
    plats:[],
    cmdElements:[]
}

export default function(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PLATS:
             return{
                 ...state,
                 plats:action.payload,
                 cmdElements:state.cmdElements
              
             }
             default : 
              return  state

        }
    
}
```