# Reduce method ? Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined error. react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi I'm trying to apply the following example [How to filter and sort the same array of object state in redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133137/how-to-filter-and-sort-the-same-array-of-object-state-in-redux)

however I've got the following error `'Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined error'`. It seems to be related to the "Pane container" and especially this helper function :

```
// Simple helper function, which return all filters from state by given key.
function getFilters(key, movies) {
  return movies.reduce((acc, movies) => {
    if (!acc.includes(movie[key])) {
      return [...acc, movie[key]];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

I think `movies` is coming from the reducer, passed from a list of items :

```
const items = [{
  title: 'Mad max',
  year: 2015,
  rating: 8,
  genre: 'fantasy',
}, {
  title: 'Spider man 2',
  year: 2014,
  rating: 7,
  genre: 'fantasy',
}];

export default function moviesReducer(state = {
  movies: items,
  year: 'all',
  rating: 'all',
  genre: 'all',
  sorting: 'year',
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_YEAR':
      return {
        ...state,
        year: action.year,
      };
    case 'SET_RATING':
      return {
        ...state,
        rating: action.rating,
      };
    case 'SET_GENRE':
      return {
        ...state,
        genre: action.genre,
      };
    case 'SET_SORTING':
      return {
        ...state,
        sorting: action.sorting,
      };
    default:
      return state;
```

So if movies need to be an array, does all this seems to be correct ?

thanks.

Comment: JSBin would be useful.

From what you're saying "movies" is not initialized  or undefined. Make sure you feed the reduce function with an array (this is important)

Comment: As about what "reduce" means, I think that MDN does a good job explaining it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: thanks for sharing. What do you mean by _you feed the reduce function with an array_ ?

Comment: reduce is very useful to transform an array (a series of values like [1, 2, 3]) to a (single) value computed from the elements of this array.  If you try to `reduce` a string or basically anything else except an array you'll get an error.

UPDATE: in the case above I meant "`movies` should be an array, empty or with elements, but not null, undefined or an object"

Comment: Ok thanks. that's more clear to me. the error doesn't let me load react dev tools, so I can't see if movies is properly passed as an array or not. I've edit my post. What do you think ? What should I do ?

Comment: @SimonBreton could you post the code invoking `getFilters()`?