# Updating displayed Item list from dropdown menu selector react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand how to filter a list of items with react/redux. I've build this example https://jsbin.com/pineyec/edit?html,console,output based on this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133137/how-to-filter-and-sort-the-same-array-of-object-state-in-redux)

After few hours and some help I finally have my filter components working correctly (I guess). However how don't really understand how I should link my filter components with my item list components.

I guess the key of my problem is in the following code but I don't really understand it :

```
// Getting visible movies from state.
function getVisibleMovies(year, genre, rating, sorting, movies) {
  return movies
    .filter(m => {
      return (
        (year == 'all' || year == m.year) &&
        (genre == 'all' || genre == m.genre) &&
        (rating == 'all' || rating == m.rating)
      );
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sorting == 'year') {
        return b.year - a.year;
      }
      if (sorting == 'rating') {
        return b.rating - a.rating;
      }
      if (sorting == 'alphabetically') {
        return a.title > b.title ? 1 : a.title < b.title ? -1 : 0;
      }
    });
}
```

Do I need to build new actions ? Or new reducer ?

What's should be my next step ?

thanks.

Comment: Are you calling this function in a render method somewhere?

Comment: yep. I've got the following error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. I'm calling it in a div is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two `mapStateToProps` functions with the same name, so you are always calling the last one.

Change

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
          return {
            movies: state.moviesReducer.movies,
          };
        }

const MovieOne = connect(mapStateToProps)(Movies);
```

to

```
 function mapStateToPropsMovies(state) {
      let {year,genre,rating,sorting,movies} =  state.moviesReducer;
      return {
        movies:  getVisibleMovies(year, genre, rating, sorting, movies)
      };
 }


 const MovieOne = connect(mapStateToPropsMovies)(Movies);
```

[jsbin working](https://jsbin.com/cihetiyuxe/1/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: Good catch. This will usually not be an issue because in general it is wise to split up your components into separate files, but in jsbin where everything is in the same file it can be a problem. An alternative is to skip creating a named function at all and simply use an anonymous function directly within the `connect` call. ie like this: http://jsbin.com/wigiyajowi/edit?js

Comment: In the same place as in the answer, if you get that error is because the param movies is undefined inside getVisibleMovies(), which means that you are not passing movies to it.