# Multiple checkbox filtering react state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, state

I'm attempting to filter state using multiple checkboxes.

I have it working to some degree, in that you can check one genre to filter the movies by that genre.

I'm struggling to 'restore state' after the checkbox is unchecked, and to also allow for multiple filters to be selected.

I've tried cloning the original state using json.stringify and also clonedeep as suggested in some of the other stackoverflow questions, but this doesn't seem to work for me and some say it's a bad way to do it all together.

I've created a stackblitz of the current state of the app here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9t8f6e

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be really grateful. Even if it's just a link to a decent article or tutorial that would be super helpful. *This community has saved my butt lately learning this stuff!*

Comment: You really should try to include in the post itself all the information needed to help you. Now the important bits are behind a link.

Comment: @SamiHult apologies - last time I posted a question everyone was asking me to put it on stackblitz so thought it would be more helpful if I did it first this time around.

Comment: check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133137/how-to-filter-and-sort-the-same-array-of-object-state-in-redux , it may help you

Comment: @Sparker Parker you are doing it wrong way. You should get all movies data and store into the state is another variable `allMovies` and then when checkbox is changed you should get all `checkboxes` and filter according to them. But keep all the `movies` in one seperate state variable

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbkfx4 ?

Comment: @Jayavel so simple! thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can go with previous answer or you can also do like below:

**First option :** Keep your all data's in two states like `movies`  and `defaultData` state

For filter and remove/cancel use `movies` and for revert back to all movies use `defaultData`

and in your example you have used componentWillMount to fetch data, use componentDidMount instead

```
// Fire API on init
componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch Genre Data
    axios.get(`${base_url}genre/movie/list?api_key=${api_key}`)
        .then(res => this.setState({ genres: res.data.genres }));

    // Fetch 'Now Playing' Data
    axios.get(`${base_url}movie/now_playing?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US&page=1`)
        .then(res => this.setState({
            movies: res.data.results, // for filter/remove
            isLoaded: true,
            defaultData: res.data.results //this will store default data
        }));
}
```

Second option:

you can create a separate file for data services and reuse it whenever need, situation like revert,undo

GetData.js

```
 import axios from 'axios';

// TMDB Info/Credentials
const base_url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
const api_key = "39b616a19667f17d8ffcaa175fc93491";


export function data() {
   return axios.get(`${base_url}movie/now_playing?api_key=${api_key}&language=en-US&page=1`)
       .then(res => res.data) 
}
```

and in App.js

```
import {data} from './components/GetData';

data().then(data=>{ 
        this.setState({
          movies: data.results,
          isLoaded: true,
        });
    });
```

demonstrated this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbkfx4)

Comment: Thank you for this. Upon putting this into practice I can see that it does work, however when you begin to uncheck some of the filters it of course doesn't apply the filters that are still checked and instead goes back to the default state. Is there a way to overcome this easily?

Comment: have you checked my second option ?

Comment: I did yes, thank you. It doesn't handle the checkboxes that are still ticked if one is removed though. It just resets to the default state.

Comment: instead going to default state , you need to sort out which are filtered, which are not ! I will update a simple work around in https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbkfx4

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @StephanieParker can you check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbkfx4 , is that you need ?

Comment: thanks that's certainly a step in the right direction I think. I'll keep playing with it. At the moment though if you select 'action' and then 'adventure' it doubles up the state, so you get 'aquaman' twice for example. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. First some important notions:

1. Updating state or props will cause rendering.
2. `filter` will create a new array.

That means you can have a method to calculate the filtered array on the fly:

```
filteredMovies = () => 
    this.state.movies.filter(movie =>
        this.state.selectedGenres.every(genreId =>
            movie.genre_ids.includes(genreId)
        )
    );
```

You can use this in your `render` method:

```
<NowPlaying movies={this.filteredMovies()} />
```

The method will be called at every render, which is triggered whenever `state.selectedGenres` is updated.

Now the missing piece is how the `state.selectedGenres` is updated, but I think you will manage that.